# Doctrine's alias doesn't have quotes identifier

Tags: sql-server, doctrine-orm, alias

Hi,

Doctrine has a problem with columns starting with an integer.
The alias it creates does not quotes identifier and thus create an error when querying SQL. What to do? Unfortunately I cannot rename the column that is already used in another program.

```
SELECT 
  t0_.[1ColName] AS 1ColName_0, 
FROM [MyTable] t0_ 
WHERE t0_.[1ColName] = 25
```

Msg 102, Niveau 15, État 1, **Ligne 2**
Syntaxe incorrecte vers **'1'**.

Comment: what do your tables look like?

Comment: If this can help you here is a SQL query very close to the CREATE TABLE that had to be done when creating the table.  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[1TableName] (
 [1l_primarykey]  [int]  NOT NULL,
 [1l_optionalkey] [int]  DEFAULT NULL,
 [1l_colValue1]  [text] DEFAULT NULL,
 [1l_colValue2]  [text] DEFAULT NULL,
);